# Check IIS is installed via regkey or Get-WindowsFeature

Tags: iis, powershell, service

I would like to check if my VM is installed with IIS.
Which method is more accurate?

**1. Registry Editor**

```
Check for regfolder and regkey
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Inetstp -> Folder must exist
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Inetstp\VersionString -> Value must be valid
```

**2. Get-WindowsFeature**

```
PS > (Get-WindowsFeature Web-Server).InstallState -eq "Installed"
```

For `Get-WindowsFeature`, some VMs reply back with InstallState as "Available". Does it mean the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supported method is with [Get-WindowsFeature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servermanager/get-windowsfeature?view=winserver2012r2-ps&viewFallbackFrom=win10-ps), because the registry keys can change at any time.

"Available" means that the feature is available for installation but is not installed

> *[Get-WindowsFeature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servermanager/get-windowsfeature?view=winserver2012r2-ps&viewFallbackFrom=win10-ps)*
>   Gets information about Windows Server roles, role services, and
>   features that are available for installation and installed on a
>   specified server.

Comment: Consider the fact that installers of all official IIS OOB components check the registry key, I don't think that's "not supported".